# JOOQ: Select columns from another table grouped by 1 column

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jooq

I'm not really sure how to explain this question, but basically I'm trying to do something like this:

```
private SelectHavingStep<Record> singleUserQuery(Collection<Condition> conditions) {
    return dsl.select(USER_T.fields())
              .select(DSL.arrayAggDistinct(PERMISSION_T.NAME).as("permissions"))
              .select(ROLE.NAME.as("role"))
              .select(ROLE.ROLE_TYPE.as("roleType"))
              .from(USER_T)
                .leftJoin(USER_ACCOUNT_PERMISSIONS)
                    .on(USER_ACCOUNT_PERMISSIONS.USER_ID.eq(USER_T.ID))
                .leftJoin(PERMISSION_T)
                    .on(PERMISSION_T.NAME.eq(USER_ACCOUNT_PERMISSIONS.PERMISSION))
                .leftJoin(ROLE)
                    .on(ROLE.ID.eq(USER_T.ROLE_ID))
              .where(conditions)
                .groupBy(USER_T.ID);
}
```

I have a `USER` table referencing the `ROLE` table by role id, and want my user results to always include role name and type from the `ROLE` table.

This is giving me the following error `PSQLException: ERROR: column "role.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. The thing is I'm not sure how to go about fixing this, and would like to hear any recommendations. I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `ROLE.NAME` and `ROLE.ROLE_TYPE` to your `GROUP BY` clause:

```
...
.groupBy(USER_T.ID, ROLE.NAME, ROLE.ROLE_TYPE)
```

Or, since this is PostgreSQL (which allows for projecting all columns with a functional dependency on the `GROUP BY` clause), adding the `ROLE.ID` column might be sufficient:

```
...
.groupBy(USER_T.ID, ROLE.ID)
```

#### Why is that the case?

One of the biggest problems SQL beginners often have is not understanding the logical order of operations in SQL clauses. In this particular case, it's important to understand that the `GROUP BY` clause "happens" logically before the `SELECT` clause, meaning that once you have grouped by a set of columns, the set of columns that is still available to `SELECT` is quite limited. As a general rule of thumb, you can only select:

- Columns (or expressions formed from columns) that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause
- Columns (or expressions formed from columns) that have a *functional dependency* on columns that appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. I.e. if you group by a primary key, all other columns of that table are functionally dependent, so they can be selected as well. (Only few databases implement this feature)
- Aggregate functions on all the other columns

More information on the order of SQL operations here: https://blog.jooq.org/2016/12/09/a-beginners-guide-to-the-true-order-of-sql-operations